# MQL4 - Why are sell orders being closed prematurely, but not buy ones?

Tags: mql4

In my custom expert advisor, the sell orders are closing immediately after opening, always at a loss. I don't have either a **`stoploss`** or **`takeprofit`** set, and I commented out all the order close functions, for troubleshooting purposes. It's not happening to buy orders, they work correctly. I only have one order open at a time. What could be causing this?

```
orderSentTicket = OrderSend( "EURUSD",
                              OP_SELL,
                              lotSize,
                              price,
                              3,      // slippage
                              0,      // stoploss
                              0,      // takeprofit
                              NULL,
                              0,
                              0,
                              clrGreen
                              );
```

The buy version doesn't have this issue. 
In the course of reducing the code to be able to include more here, I see it looks like the issue may be in a trailing stop include function from a 3rd party I used. It seems to be compiling differently because the error started when I just changed a comment in the main code & recompiled. When I don't use the trailing stop the problem goes away. If this turns out to be the issue I will elaborate here if it looks like it will benefit anyone else, otherwise I will delete the question. Thanks for the feedback I have received so far.

Comment: **Welcome to StackOverflow**. It might be helpful to review the post, so as to add more details and better meet the Community standards and practices, best by the promoted MCVE-based presentation of the subject matter -- **https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve** Feel free to revise and update your post, so as to also allow to see the whole code that can reproduce the problem and would be great to also post the error-log / MetaTrader Terminal 4 [Journal] data, that illustrate both the Terminal- and Broker-side responses to the XTO instructions and confirm / explain the objected phenomenon. Thanks

Comment: There is not enough information to explain the reason. You might want to post the content of Expert tab, and also explain the closing mechanism.